# How to output all elements in a JSON string to a table using Panda

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to scrape a table of results from a webpage and ultimately write those results to a csv file. I've gotten as far as scraping the page, using BeautifulSoup, extracting the JSON string that contains the data I need and getting Pandas to output that table, but but it only seems to be printing the table outline, and not containing any of the row details.

My code is below (very new to programming as it probably shows!):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
url = '[url_im_scraping]'
headers = urllib3.util.make_headers(basic_auth='[username/password]')
response = http.request('GET', url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup (response.data, 'html.parser')
#This extracts the initial table of data
grid_data = soup.find("script", class_="__allTestPointsOfSelectedSuite")
data = json.loads(grid_data.text)
#This was to remove the column settings part of the table
testtest = grid_data.text.split("testPoints")
#Putting "{" and the initial key back into the string and loading into JSON object
print(pd.read_json("{" + "\"testPoints" + testtest[1]))
```

When I load my JSON string into a JSON table creating website like json2table, it correctly displays and validates as a valid JSON string, and outputs something like this:

```
testpoints
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 etc...
totalPointsCount
```

When I try to output the JSON string as a table using Pandas, I get the following:

```
                                           testPoints  totalPointsCount
0   {'assignedTo': 'a5060ed2-6b1c-4da3-add0-0d6d97...                17
1   {'assignedTo': 'a5060ed2-6b1c-4da3-add0-0d6d97...                17
2   {'assignedTo': 'a5060ed2-6b1c-4da3-add0-0d6d97...                17
3   {'assignedTo': 'a5060ed2-6b1c-4da3-add0-0d6d97...                17
4   {'assignedTo': 'a5060ed2-6b1c-4da3-add0-0d6d97...                17
5   {'assignedTo': 'a5060ed2-6b1c-4da3-add0-0d6d97...                17
6   {'assignedTo': 'a5060ed2-6b1c-4da3-add0-0d6d97...                17
7   {'assignedTo': 'a5060ed2-6b1c-4da3-add0-0d6d97...                17
8   {'assignedTo': 'a5060ed2-6b1c-4da3-add0-0d6d97...                17
9   {'assignedTo': 'a5060ed2-6b1c-4da3-add0-0d6d97...                17
10  {'assignedTo': 'a5060ed2-6b1c-4da3-add0-0d6d97...                17
11  {'assignedTo': 'a5060ed2-6b1c-4da3-add0-0d6d97...                17
12  {'assignedTo': 'a5060ed2-6b1c-4da3-add0-0d6d97...                17
13  {'assignedTo': 'a5060ed2-6b1c-4da3-add0-0d6d97...                17
14  {'assignedTo': 'a5060ed2-6b1c-4da3-add0-0d6d97...                17
15  {'assignedTo': 'a5060ed2-6b1c-4da3-add0-0d6d97...                17
16  {'assignedTo': 'a5060ed2-6b1c-4da3-add0-0d6d97...                17
```

I am not sure how to also display the nested fields within the two keys of 'testPoints' and 'totalPoundsCount'.

Example of how I want to get the output here (generated with Json2table):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTtp2.jpg

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction of where I'm going wrong.

Edit: I have now changed max column width and see I'm getting the entire string returned as such:

```
{'assignedTo': 'a5060ed2', 'automated': 'Not Automated', 'build': None, 'configurationId': 123, 'configurationName': 'Package 1.0', 'lastResultState': 1, 'lastRunBy': '', 'lastRunDuration': 0, 'mostRecentResultOutcome': 2, 'mostRecentRunId': 1234, 'outcome': 'Passed', 'state': 2, 'suiteId': 1234, 'suiteName': Name', 'testCaseId': 12345, 'testPointId': 12345, 'tester': 'Fred Smith', 'workItemProperties': [{'Key': 'System.Id', 'Value': 12345}, {'Key': 'System.Title', 'Value': 'Item Item'}, {'Key': 'System.IterationPath', 'Value': 'Path\Path'}, {'Key': 'System.ChangedDate', 'Value': '/Date(1554200489873)/'}, {'Key': 'System.ChangedBy', 'Value': 'Fred Smith'}, {'Key': 'Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomationStatus', 'Value': 'Not Automated'}]}
```

, but I am still struggling with how to get 'assignedTo' etc from that string as column headings, i.e:

```
assignedTo     Automated       Build
123456789      Not Automated   None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below converts a string dictionary to a dataframe. The Step-2 below could be looped over the entire string table. This loop could have `append()` to compile all records into one dataframe.

**Step-1:**
In this example, assigned the string to a variable:

```
df = {'assignedTo': 'a5060ed2', 'automated': 'Not Automated', 'build': None, 'configurationId': 123, 
      'configurationName': 'Package 1.0', 'lastResultState': 1, 'lastRunBy': '', 'lastRunDuration': 0, 
      'mostRecentResultOutcome': 2, 'mostRecentRunId': 1234, 'outcome': 'Passed', 'state': 2, 
      'suiteId': 1234, 'suiteName': 'Name', 'testCaseId': 12345, 'testPointId': 12345, 'tester': 'Fred Smith', 
      'workItemProperties': [{'Key': 'System.Id', 'Value': 12345}, {'Key': 'System.Title', 'Value': 'Item Item'}, 
                             {'Key': 'System.IterationPath', 'Value': 'Path\Path'}, 
                             {'Key': 'System.ChangedDate', 'Value': '/Date(1554200489873)/'}, 
                             {'Key': 'System.ChangedBy', 'Value': 'Fred Smith'}, 
                             {'Key': 'Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomationStatus', 'Value': 'Not Automated'}]}
```

**Step-2:**

Convert string to a dataframe:

```
temp = pd.DataFrame({'assignedTo':[df['assignedTo']], 'automated':[df['automated']], 'build':[df['build']]}) 
temp
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I'm getting the following error:````temp = pd.DataFrame({'assignedTo':[df['assignedTo']], 'automated':[df['automated']], 'build':[df['build']]})
TypeError: string indices must be integers````. It seems to be expecting df[1] rather than a string?

Comment: Ok, so I have my string stored in variable 'content3'. If I print that variable to console, and then copy the out put into 'DF =' it works fine, if I try saying 'DF=content3' then I get the string indices error message. I am not sure why it accepts it I copy and paste the output from that string variable into the script, but won't accept the string variable directly?

Comment: Ahh cracked it. I did print(type(content3)) and saw that it was showing a type of string but print(type(df)) was showing a type of dict. Did some googling and tried ````df= json.loads(content3)```` which loaded it as a dict type instead of string, and now it all works. This is more than enough for me to get further ahead, many thanks!